# How to sort a two dimensional array by smallest number?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm making a program that counts how many lines of code are in a folder where you input the extension you want to check for (like `.cs`) and it lists all of the files with that extension and their lines of code like this:

```
1. BackgroundProcesses.cs: 153
2. App.xaml.cs: 15
3. MainTableManifest.cs: 41
```

At the moment, I'm just using `Directory.GetFiles()` to get the files and they're not in any particular order. However, I want to sort each file by how many lines it has to display it from smallest to largest for easy viewing of what the largest files are with an output like this:

```
1. App.xaml.cs: 15
2. MainTableManifest.cs: 41
3. BackgroundProcesses.cs: 153
```

Here's what my two-dimensional *jagged* array basically looks like:

```
string[][] arr = new string[][] {
    new string[]{"file1", "324"},
    new string[]{"file2", "1903"},
    new string[]{"file3", "617"}
};
```

Obviously, I would need to convert the strings to numbers when sorting (I don't think you can have a jagged array with different array types). Any ideas on how to do this to convert that jagged array to something like this?

```
string[][] arr = new string[][] {
    new string[]{"file1", "324"},
    new string[]{"file2", "617"},
    new string[]{"file3", "1903"}
};
```

Comment: Don't use a two dimensional array of strings. Use a collection (likely a `List<>`) of typed  objects. A type that has two properties, `Name` (a string) and `LineCount` (an int). Your program will become much simpler

Comment: Take a look at @rossgurbutt's answer. Implement it, see if you can make sense of it. That's the classic object-oriented solution to your problem. You should have a good grasp of that before you look at the other _tuple_-based solutions. You could try combining the two approaches; start with objects, and then use LINQ to sort and fetch your ultimate answer

Comment: You can use value tuple or dictionary instead of 2d array

Comment: Please use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles, especially if your directories can have a high number of files. You'll thank yourself later, especially if you use the suggested solution of storing info in a strongly typed collection (or even the value tuple approach) where you'd just discard the array from GetFiles anyhow

Answer (score 1):

You should use ValueTuple instead of Jagged Arrays.

```
(string Filename, int Lines)[] files = ...
```

After that you can use Linq for sorting

```
var sorted = files
    .OrderBy(item => item.Lines)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the major points of an object oriented programming language such as C# is to allow you to define custom objects and have behaviours related to them rather than complex structures of native types.

Have you tried creating a custom object to represent this data that can then be sorted accordingly?
e.g.

```
public class FileRecord
{
    public string FileName { get; }
    public int NumberOfLines { get; }

    public FileRecord(string fileName, int numberOfLines)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.NumberOfLines = numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

Then you can either make this class implement IComparable or define a custom comparer for the sort. My preference would be for using a custom comparer because you may want to sort using different criteria and the same class elsewhere.

This would look like:

```
public class FileRecordComparer : IComparer<FileRecord>
{
    public int Compare(FileRecord x, FileRecord y)
    {
        // Could handle nulls here if you're expecting nulls

        int lineCompare = x.NumberOfLines.CompareTo(y.NumberOfLines);

        if (lineCompare == 0)
            return x.FileName.CompareTo(y.FileName);
        else
            return lineCompare;
    }
}
```

Then you can have the following code to sort your array (you'll have to populate it in the way you are currently of course)

```
        // Could use a list here if you don't know the number of files
        FileRecord[] records = new FileRecord[numberOfFiles];
        // ...
        // Populate the records as you do currently, but creating instances of FileRecord
        // ...
        Array.Sort(records, new FileRecordComparer());
```

Comment: This should handle the case when number of lines is equal. For example by then sorting on  the file name. Otherwise a stable sort isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

you could use Tuple with Linq to simplify your problem get the files and number of lines in same time:

```
(string Filename, int numberLines)[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\", "*.cs")
                                                      .Select(f => (f, File.ReadLines(f).Count()))
                                                      .OrderBy(f => f.Item2).ToArray();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"file:{file.Filename} lines:{file.numberLines}");
        }
```

if you have lot of files in your directory, i suggest you to use [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.1) instead of GetFiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var files = arr.OrderBy(x =>Convert.ToInt64(x[1]));
```

Comment: Anything specific I should be looking at?